# How is this the Open Mapping Theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

My book has this theorem which it has stated as the Open Mapping Theorem:

> Suppose X and Y are Banach spaces and $T \in B(X,Y)$ is surjective.
>
> Let: $L=\{T(x): x \in X \text{ and } \|x\|\le 1\}$,
>
> with closure $\bar{L}$. Then:
>
> (a) there exists $r >0$ such that $\{y \in Y: \|y\|\le r\}\subseteq
> \bar{L}$;
>
> (b) $\{y \in Y: \|y\| \le \frac{r}{2}\}\subseteq L$
>
> (c) if, in addition, T is one-to-one then T is invertible.

But how does this say that an open set in X maps to an open set in Y? If I assume (c) then it holds, because then the inverse is bounded(and hence continuous), and then since T is the inverse of the inverse and a function is continuous iff open sets maps to open sets, we have the result. But what if T is not 1-1?

I tried something like this:

Let $V\subseteq X$ be open. Then we must show that T(V) is open. Let $y \in T(V)$ we must show that there exists an open ball: $B_y(\epsilon)\subseteq T(V)$ . Since T is surjective, there is an x such that $T(x)=y$. Since V is open there is an open ball such that $B_x(\delta)\subseteq V$. $B_x(\delta)=\{z \in X: \|x-z\|<\delta\}$. We also then have that the closed ball $B_x(\delta/2)\subseteq V$, $B_x(\delta/2)=\{z \in X:\|z-x\|\le\delta/2\}=\{z \in X: \|(z-x)\frac{2}{\delta}\|\le1\}$.

Now the set:
$\{z \in X: \|(z-x)\frac{2}{\delta}\|\le1\}$, reminds of $\{x \in X: \|x\| \le 1\}$(stated in the theorem). But I am not sure quite how to relate this, and how to finish my proof.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think the Theorem works better if we write $L=\{Tx:\ \|x\|<1\}$.

Note that $B_x(\delta)=x+B_0(\delta)=x+\delta\,B_0(1)$. So 
$$
TB_x(\delta)=Tx+\delta\,TB_0(1)= y+\delta L.
$$
By the Theorem, there exists $r>0$ with $B_0(r)\subset L$. Then $$B_y(\delta r)=y+\delta B_0(r)\subset y+\delta L=TB_x(\delta).$$
So $V$ is open.